# join SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java, javascript, sql, command, spring-jdbc

i have a problem with a join statement

```
 String q1="select e.employee_id,e.manager_id,e.first_name,e.last_name,e.salary,e.commission_pct,d.manager_id,d.employee_id from employees as e ,employees as d where  e.manager_id=d.employee_id and e.employee_id="+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    try{
        OracleDataSource ods=new OracleDataSource();
        ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@localhost:1521/XE");
        Connection con=ods.getConnection();

        Statement s=con.createStatement();
        s.execute(q1);
        ResultSet rs=s.getResultSet();
        String x=(String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        while(rs.next()){
            if (x.equals(rs.getString("e.employee_id"))){
                jTextField1.setText(rs.getString("e.first_name"));
                jTextField2.setText(rs.getString("e.last_name"));
                jTextField3.setText(rs.getString("e.salary"));
                jTextField4.setText(rs.getString("e.commission_pct"));
                jTextField5.setText(rs.getString("d.first_name"));
            }
        }
        con.close();

    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

how could i solve this problem ?!
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: what's the type of employee_id?

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com). Sit back and relax. Someone'll pwn your server soon and make your problem moot.

Comment: if you're getting an exception, can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really be using prepared statement to avoid SQL injection problem. Anyways your issue is:

```
select e.employee_id,e.manager_id,e.first_name,e.last_name,e.salary,e.commission_pct,d.manager_id,d.employee_id 
from employees as e ,employees as d 
where  e.manager_id=d.employee_id 
and e.employee_id="+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
```

I see you use rs.getString for employee_id, so you are missing quotes for e.employee_id field in where clause.